# Does TEXT_DETECTION work on images of the vertical spine of a book?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

Subject pretty much sums it up: if an image has text in a vertical orientation - like the spine of a book - does TEXT_DETECTION work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work just as well with that orientation.

Answer (score 0):

It should Work. 
illustration

[Book Spine Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1iJ1.png)

Results

```
 "responses": [
{
  "textAnnotations": [
    {
      "locale": "en",
      "description": "Catch\nJoseph Heller\nVINTAGE\n",
      "boundingPoly": {
        "vertices": [
          {
            "x": 141,
            "y": 197
          },
          {
            "x": 291,
            "y": 197
          },
          {
            "x": 291,
            "y": 2065
          },
          {
            "x": 141,
            "y": 2065
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```